# Why is this invalid in JS

Tags: javascript

Why is this valid is JS:

```
const a = ['b', 'c'];
a.d = 'e';
a.x = { y: 'z' };
console.log(a); // ['b', 'c', d: 'e', x: { y: 'z' }]
```

But this is not:

```
const a = ['b', 'c', d: 'e', x: { y: 'z' }];
console.log(a);
```

How can we build such an array in one step?

Comment: This isn't an array. In the first code, you're using an array as a map, which isn't going to be useful. How are you planning to use this structure?

Comment: if you want to have alphanumerical indexes in Javascript, and use the syntax `d: 'e'`, you **must** use objects, not arrays which have numerical indexes

Comment: are u sure first one is valid ?

Comment: OP: Your premise is wrong, `console.log(a)` does not output what you claim it does.

Comment: I presume this is what you're going for `const a = ['b', 'c', {d: 'e'}, {x: { y: 'z' }}];`?

Comment: @DenysSéguret arrays are essentially objects, I don't plan to use it, just trying to understand JS better

Comment: @Kaddath you are right, I'm not trying to do that though

Comment: @NozarSafari yes, write it in your console

Comment: @ChrisG it does, did you try it in Chrome or in node console?

Comment: i'm afraid to say  @user5470921 right  ! but i think what u see in comsole.log  is not what excatly exist. `const a = ['b', 'c', {d: 'e'}, {x: { y: 'z' }}]` is real value

Comment: @AndrewBone nope, just trying to understand why the first on is valid and the other isn't, this structure isn't that useful, but it's an interesting case to examine

Comment: @user5470921 the first one isn't valid , though would be if you weren't using const

Comment: @AndrewBone it's, write in your console, I thought it wasn't at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing array and object literals.

```
['a', 'b']
```

is an array literal, creating an array of length 2 containing two strings.

```
{a: 1, b: 2}
```

is an object literal, creating an object with two values at two keys.

Your first example adds aditional values under keys to an array. This is possible because every array is also an object. This can (afaik) not be done via a literal.

Comment: Exactly, arrays are essentially objects so it's valid. "This can (afaik) not be done via a literal", that's what I am trying to understand, why?

Comment: Because the literals are separate, the array literal can only initialize the array content, not any additional key/value pairs. If you ask me for why it is designed that way: I am not a part of the W3C and do not know.

Answer (score 1):

A JavaScript `Array` is really a "class" so an instance of an array is really an object. This is also what `typeof [1 , 2 ,3]` says.

There's general things you can do with JavaScript objects like adding properties or overriding existing properties for example override the length with whatever you want or add custom methods on it.

```js
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];

arr.length = 100;
arr.thirditem = function () {
    return this[3];
}.bind(arr);
console.log(arr.length);
console.log(arr.thirditem());
```

We need to note that reading from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

> The JavaScript Array object is a global object that is used in the construction of arrays; which are high-level, list-like objects.
>   [...]
>
> ## Syntax
>
> ```
> [element0, element1, ..., elementN]
> new Array(element0, element1[, ...[, elementN]])
> new Array(arrayLength)
> ```

The initialization rule for arrays needs to obey JavaScript syntax rules for arrays noted above so it needs to strictly be of the form `[ "comma", "separated", "values" ]` or use the `new Array("comma", "separated", "values")` format (or `new Array(length)` format if you just need an array of N values).

Comment: So we build an array using the suggested syntax (can't do it any other way by design), then it's implemented as an object, only then we can manipulate its properties, which allowed the first snippet to work. Am I following correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You need to follow syntax rules but after that JavaScript allows you to manipulate any object in a lot of ways (even functions can have properties because they are technically objects as well)

Answer (score 0):

An array element is not an array property. You declare an array by listing zero or more elements between square brackets, and you declare its properties with the dot notation.
This can't be done in "one step" as you ask, because they're essentially different things.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object as container and add all array values with ther index. For iterating the array values, you could assign these values to an array with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const a = { 0: 'b', 1: 'c', d: 'e', x: { y: 'z' } };

console.log(a);
console.log(Object.assign([], a)); // take the array values
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting is that JavaScript could allow the following syntax --

```
var arr = [some: "someVal", other: "otherVal"];
```

which would be equal to

```
var arr = [];

arr.some = "someVal";
arr.other = "otherVal";
```

Would there be a significant number of real-world use cases for such an array?

A language doesn't come with an infinite set of features, some of which get "thrown out" eventually. Instead, the features are *added* to the language.

Adding features to the language is not free. They must be designed, implemented and tested.

Apparently, adding this syntax was not considered worthwhile.

Comment: I'm not suggesting adding this structure, writing the first snippet in the console works, whereas the other one doesn't, I'm trying to figure out why, to learn the language better, and yes I do agree this structure isn't useful, it's already allowed however